# The wordpress api POST request in order to create a post through java returns 403 forbidden only for specific post

Tags: java

The `wordpress API` returns `403 forbidden` for specific post whereas for other posts works fine

Tried to change the `authCookie` but it did not work.

```
    LOG.info("Creating post with title:" + title);

    String nonce = getNonceForCreatePost(authCookie);

    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(createPostUrl);
    post.addHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");

    List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nonce", nonce));
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cookie", authCookie));
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("status", status));
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("title", title));
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("content", content));
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("categories", Utils.listToCommaSeparated(categories)));
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tags", Utils.listToCommaSeparated(tags)));
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("author", author));

    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, "UTF-8"));

    CloseableHttpResponse res = httpClient.execute(post);

int code = res.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

I expect `200 OK` response code.

Comment: OS, Wordpress lib version info required. Spam also relevant event/errorlog info.

Comment: Found it, the reason was some SVG elements in the content. Thanks though.

Comment: post it as an answer and show how you fixed it.. otherwise the question stays open for eternity and nobody learns from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, the reason was some SVG elements in the content,after the removal of them everything is ok